# Numpy - np.multiply() results in nan in version 1.21.3

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 environments:

**Environment #1 (old):**

```
Python 3.7.5
Numpy 1.15.4
```

**Environment #2 (new):**

```
Python 3.8.10
Numpy 1.21.3
```

When I run the following code in **Environment #2 (new)**, it does not result in the same output as in **Environment #1 (old)**:

```
>>> # THIS IS OUTPUT FROM Environment #2 (new)
>>> df[attr.AMOUNT_GL]
8    112.233446
9    112.233446
Name: AMOUNT_GL, dtype: float64
>>> 
>>> sub_asset_gr_amount
112.23344556677898
>>> 
>>> df.loc[_filter, attr.KEY]
9    0.5
Name: KEY, dtype: float64
>>> 
>>> np.multiply((df[attr.AMOUNT_GL] / sub_asset_gr_amount), df.loc[_filter, attr.KEY])
8    NaN # <<- This is a difference
9    0.5
dtype: float64
>>>
```

The `df` and the other variables have completely the same values in **Environment #1 (old)**, but, the result of `np.multiply()` looks like this:

```
>>> # THIS IS OUTPUT FROM Environment #1 (old)
>>> df[attr.AMOUNT_GL]
8    112.233446
9    112.233446
Name: AMOUNT_GL, dtype: float64
>>> 
>>> sub_asset_gr_amount
112.23344556677898
>>> 
>>> df.loc[_filter, attr.KEY]
9    0.5
Name: KEY, dtype: float64
>>> np.multiply((df[attr.AMOUNT_GL] / sub_asset_gr_amount), df.loc[_filter, attr.KEY])
8    0.5 # <<- This is a difference
9    0.5
Name: AMOUNT_GL, dtype: float64
>>>
```

The **difference** is specifically in this line in the output of `np.multiply()`:
`8    NaN` vs `8    0.5`

How do I make sure that in my **Environment #2 (new)** the result is the same as in **Environment #1 (old)**? In essence, how do I make the output of `np.multiply()` to be `8    0.5` instead of `8    NaN`?

Thank you very much

Comment: can you add what `df` is defined as?

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

At the end I ended up with this code:

```
        # Create a diff DataFrame which contains only rows to multiply
        df_diff = df.join(df.loc[_filter], how="inner", rsuffix="_r")
        # Remove suffixed columns from df_diff since they only contain duplicate values
        df_diff.drop(df_diff.filter(regex='_r$').columns.tolist(), axis=1, inplace=True)
        # Calculate the weighted portion to be added to the original key
        calculated_numbers = np.multiply((df_diff[attr.AMOUNT_GL] / sub_asset_gr_amount), df_diff.loc[_filter, attr.KEY])

        # Apply the calculated numbers to df_diff
        df_diff.loc[:, attr.KEY] = df_diff[attr.KEY] + calculated_numbers 
        # Merge back and replace the values in df with values from df_diff
        df.update(df_diff)
```